# How do I remove carriage returns with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, shell

I have a script with carriage returns in code ex:

```
$q = $this->db->prepare("\n\t\t\tINSERT INTO hb_orders(`id`,`number`,`payment_module`,`client_id`,`invoice_id`,\n\t\t\t`total`,`date_created`,`status`,`order_ip`,`notes`) VALUES (\n\t\t\t'',:number,:module,:client,:invoice,\n\t\t\t:total,:date,:status,:ip,:notes\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t");


$q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT dom.*, p.options as tld_options, p.ns as tld_ns, p.nsips as tld_nsip FROM hb_domains dom\r\n            LEFT JOIN hb_domain_prices p ON p.product_id=dom.tld_id\r\n            WHERE dom.id=?  LIMIT 1");

$query = "SELECT mc.*, mc.settings as module_config FROM hb_modules_configuration mc\r\n                WHERE mc.active='1' AND (mc.settings LIKE '%isobserver%' ";
```

How I can remove all they with php code?

Thank you.

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? MySQL should have no problem running these queries.

Comment: `\n` isn't a carriage return, it's a line feed (or new line) character: `\r` is a carriage return character

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [str_replace() function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php):

```
$a = str_replace(array("\n", "\t"), '', $a);
```

This will remove every `\n` and `\t` from the `$a` string (and replace them by nothing, actually).

Comment: Because you used single quotes.

Comment: @Glavić nice eye spotting that

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $str);
```

Comment: `str_replace` will be much faster for this specific task.

Comment: @DainisAbols: still, it is nice to have multiple different answers how it can be done.